# Getting a Gradle verion error even thoughn I appear to have the correct version installed

Tags: gradle, gradlew

I get this error when I run a Gradle build:

```
$ ./gradlew clean build

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file '/Users/paulcarron/Documents/Documents/Books/Learning Spring Boot 2/learning-spring-boot-2/build.gradle' line: 2

* What went wrong:
An exception occurred applying plugin request [id: 'org.springframework.boot', version: '2.3.1.RELEASE']
> Failed to apply plugin [id 'org.springframework.boot']
   > Spring Boot plugin requires Gradle 5 (5.6.x only) or Gradle 6 (6.3 or later). The current version is Gradle 6.0.1

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 759ms
```

I have Gradne 6.5 installed though:

```
$ gradle -v

------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 6.5
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2020-06-02 20:46:21 UTC
Revision:     a27f41e4ae5e8a41ab9b19f8dd6d86d7b384dad4

Kotlin:       1.3.72
Groovy:       2.5.11
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.10.7 compiled on September 1 2019
JVM:          1.8.0_121 (Oracle Corporation 25.121-b13)
OS:           Mac OS X 10.15.5 x86_64
```

What could the problem be here?

Comment: Try `./gradle wrapper --gradle-version 6.5`. Gradle != Gradlew.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just to nuance the correct answer in the comments.

The program `gradle`, if you have it, invokes Gradle installed on your system. It's likely found from your PATH variable.

The `gradlew` script (notice the 'w') is a wrapper script that is usually added to the Git repository. It invokes a declared version of Gradle, automatically downloading it beforehand if necessary. It uses its own installation folder (by default `~/.gradle/wrapper`) and the version is declared in `[repo]/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties`).

While you can change the version by hand, it is better to run `./gradle wrapper --gradle-version 6.5 --distribution-type all` as this will also update the wrapper script itself if needed.